# While loop with true false without increment

Tags: c++

The code is of while loop .Now one thing i don't understand in this code is how long will loop function in this code

```
while (vis[j] == false ) 
 {
    sum += a[j] ;
    num++;
    if (a[j] < min_val) 
    {
        min_val = a [j];
    }
    vis[j] = true;
    j = place [a[j]];
 }
```

The above code is the extract from the code I got for silly sort problem on a blog.

http://isolvedaproblem.blogspot.in/2012/02/silly-sort.html?m=1

Comment: specify source please... if it's not your code

Comment: This loop is apparently only executing one time because `vis[j]` is changed to true either way. Please remember to format your code the next time you ask a question.

Comment: @Valinho Did you see `j = place [a [j]];` ?

Comment: http://isolvedaproblem.blogspot.in/2012/02/silly-sort.html?m=1

Comment: `j` is changed on the last line of the loop, so we are potentially testing a different `vis[j]` on each turn thru the `while`.

Comment: ...so the answer is "anything between 0 and the length of vis"

Comment: How many times this will loop depends on the contents of the arras `vis` and `place` along with the initial value of `j`

Comment: Again, "anything between 0 and the length of vis". We can't say anything else without the array contents.

Comment: Did you read the article? It will loop until it has found a "cycle" of swaps in the array.

Answer (score 1):

In the above code, sum, num, and min_val are irrelevant to the number of times it iterates, so the loop simply becomes:

```
while (vis[j] == false ) 
{
  vis[j] = true;
  j = place [a[j]];
}
```

So it will iterate as many times as it takes before it hits a true value in vis[j] which is as many times as the chain allows.  It may be 0 times or it could be up to length(vis).  It's a loop of O(n) = n.